# Identify Dates in DataFrame - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
    Datetime
0   2022-06-01 00:00:00 0
1   2022-06-01 00:01:00 0
2   2022-06-01 00:02:00 0
3   2022-06-01 00:03:00 0
4   2022-06-01 00:04:00 0
```

How to identify the hour is `"00"`, and so for the minutes and seconds. My requirement is to later on like to put them in a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S 0') # what is the 0?

df['hour_0'] = s.dt.hour.eq(0)
df['min_0'] = s.dt.minute.eq(0)
df['sec_0'] = s.dt.second.eq(0)
```

Output:

```
                Datetime  hour_0  min_0  sec_0
0  2022-06-01 00:00:00 0    True   True   True
1  2022-06-01 00:01:00 0    True  False   True
2  2022-06-01 00:02:00 0    True  False   True
3  2022-06-01 00:03:00 0    True  False   True
4  2022-06-01 00:04:00 0    True  False   True
```

Comment: thanks for the help, i will try it 
the 0 in the final of the row is sth that i cannot rid of ...i have tried with many ways but i cant delete it

Comment: It's fine, if it's always there add it to the `format` as I did, if not please provide more examples

Comment: due to the fact that i am a beginner in programming there is sth i didint understand 
how does the python program "understands" that for example the s.dt.minute.eq(0) refers to the minutes ?

Comment: however the 0 in the last potition 2022-06-01 00:00:00 0 is remaining as it is in the dataframe i cannot delete it.

Comment: Because `to_datetime` converts the string to `Timestamp` and `dt.minute` extracts the minutes component of the timestamp.

Comment: As said above the 0 is not an issue. If you want to change the column, use `df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S 0')` and you'll get Timestamps

Comment: my issue is that i dont need the 0 in my dataframe...i have to delete it

Comment: Then see my comment above. Other option: `df['Datetime'] = df['Datetime'].str.replace(r' 0$', '', regex=True)`

Comment: thank you so much...the zero is gone

Answer (score 0):

You can easily extract hours, minutues, seconds directly from date time string. what is extra `0`?. If you have extra strings then simply filter first then extra parameters.

```
df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'].str.split(' ').str[1],format='%H:%M:%S')
df['hour'] = df['new'].dt.hour
df['minute'] = df['new'].dt.minute
df['second'] = df['new'].dt.second
del df['new']
```

Gives #

```
             Datetime      hour  minute  second
0  2022-06-01 00:00:00 0     0       0       0
1  2022-06-01 00:01:00 0     0       1       0
2  2022-06-01 00:02:00 0     0       2       0
3  2022-06-01 00:03:00 0     0       3       0
4  2022-06-01 00:04:00 0     0       4       0
```

**Explination:**

your date string looks likes this

```
2022-06-01 00:02:00 0
```

analysis

```
2022 - Year - %y
06   - Month - %m
01   - Day   - %d

00:  - hours  - %H
02:  - minutes - %M
00:  - Seconds - %S
```

You have an extra `0`in date format to filter that I've split the string by space.

```
df['Datetime'].str.split(' ').str[1],format='%H:%M:%S'
```

Logically iplies

```
'2022-06-01 00:02:00 0'.split(' ').str[1],format='%H:%M:%S'
```

Which wraps elemnts to list sep by spaces.

```
[2022-06-01, 00:02:00, 0]
```

Analysis

```
0th elemnt in list = 2022-06-01
1st elemnt in list = 00:02:00
2nd elemnt in list = 0
```

Currently we are interested in time which is `1st elemnt in list = 00:02:00`

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'].str.split(' ').str[1],format='%H:%M:%S')
```

Pandas has inbuilt time series functions - [pandas.Series.dt.minute](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.minute.html)

Comment: could you explain me how does the str.split(' ').str[1],format='%H:%M:%S' makes the for example df['new'].dt.minute to appear the minutes ? 
i cant understand the "mechanism" of that python "order" works

Comment: @coder_21 upadted

Answer (score 0):

So, your question is a bit unclear to me, but if I understand correctly you just need to extract the hours from your DF? If so the easiest way to do this is to use Pandas inbuilt datetime functionality. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["2022-12-12 01:59:00"], ["2022-13-12 01:59:00"]])
print(df)
```

This will yield:

```
                     0
0  2022-12-12 01:59:00
1   2022-12-13 01:59:00
```

Now can do:

```
pd['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
pd['hour'] = pd['timestamp'].dt.hour
```

You can do this for minutes and seconds etc. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the advice . bucause i am beginner with programming there is sth i didn't understand 
how does the programm "understands" that df[0] refers to hours?

Comment: its the default starting index in python. I didn't give a column name when i created the dataframe and thus the col name becomes zero. Thus df[0] is saying, "grab the zeroth column of df" i.e. the first column of the df. Does that make sense?